# Concatenating Various Tables In Lua

Tags: sorting, loops, lua

I've been searching for answer to this question for a couple of days i manages to somehow use a trick to just omit this Concatenation part and just use several seperate loops to re-insert different values into the same table...
but my question is

> By default, table.sort uses < to compare array elements, so it can
>   only sort arrays of numbers or arrays of strings. Write a comparison
>   function that allows table.sort to sort arrays of mixed types. In the
>   sorted array, all values of a given type should be grouped together.
>   Within each such group, numbers and strings should be sorted as usual,
>   and other types should be sorted in some arbitrary but consistent way.

```
A = { {} , {} , {} , "" , "a", "b" , "c" , 1 , 2 , 3 , -100 , 1.1 , function() end , function() end , false , false , true }
```

as i said i solved this using different for loops but is there a way to just analyse every element of the table then assign it to a different Table??? Like : "Tables,Funcs,Nums,Strings,..." then after analysing finished just concatenate them together to have the same table just in sorted version.

My Inefficient Answer To This Was :

```
function Sep(val)
local NewA = {}

   for i in pairs(val) do
      if type(val[i]) == "string" then
     table.insert(NewA,val[i])
      end
   end
for i in pairs(val) do
      if type(val[i]) == "number" then
     table.insert(NewA,val[i])
      end
   end

for i in pairs(val) do
      if type(val[i]) == "function" then
     table.insert(NewA,tostring(val[i]))
      end
   end

for i in pairs(val) do
      if type(val[i]) == "table" then
     table.insert(NewA,tostring(val[i]))
      end
   end

for i in pairs(val) do
      if type(val[i]) == "boolean" then
     table.insert(NewA,tostring(val[i]))
      end
   end

for i in pairs(NewA) do
   print(NewA[i])
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to sort them first by type and then by value:
You can write your own custom predicate and pass it to sort

```
-- there would be need of custom < function since tables cannot be compared
-- you can overload operator < as well I suppose.
 function my_less (lhs, rhs)
    if (type (lhs) ~= "number" or type (lhs) ~= "string") then
        return tostring (lhs) < tostring (rhs) 
    else
        return lhs < rhs;
    end;
 end;

 -- the custom predicate I mentioned
 function sort_predicate (a,b)
    -- if the same type - compare variable, else compare types
    return (type (a) == type (b) and my_less (a, b)) or type (a) < type (b);
 end

 table.sort (A, sort_predicate);
```

Comment: you could boil this whole thing down to like 4 lines. all you need to do is check if the type(lhs) == "number" and if so return lhs < rhs, otherwise you return tostring(lhs) < tostring(rhs), right? there isn't really any reason to check for the various types when you're doing the same thing for everything but numbers.

Comment: i don't get why we have to enter two values in the my_less function?
isn't it just an input for of type Table in a function and then just sorting that thing out in a pre-defined manner...?

Comment: It's a comparison function- you *compare*. Comparison inherently involves comparing at least two objects.

Comment: I was trying to imply that for each type you can write any kind of opreator< . They don't have to be tostring < tostring. In any case I have not even mentioned all types like threads or userdata.

Comment: I just updated the question an added my question which as @MikeCorcoran Mentioned there's no need for extera types especially the way i did it, but could you pleae explain the code a little bit more, i'm new following "Programming in Lua, Wrox"

==>> and i didn't get the answer for a way of concatenating two or more different table values together and adding them into a Single Table holding all of them.

Comment: It's All Working Thank U All, Just Please If U see this Is there a way? by concatenation i mean :
table.concat(A[i],B[i]," , ") of course this isn't right just demonstrating what's in my mind and ....i don't mean only one element i mean the whole table A & whole Table B to become one.

Comment: `table.concat` contacts the elements of the table into string. [(click link)](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.concat) Btw it is not bad idea to go and read [some of this](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) It is not that boring as far as manuals go and it is not that long

Comment: obviously i've read this that's why i'm asking because i know there isn't a built-in function to do that...
maybe i should change my question to how put elements of various tables into one in the same time...

Answer (score 0):

```
A = { {}, {}, {}, "", "a", "b", "c", "2", "12", 1, 2, 3, -100, 1.1, 12, 11,
  function() end, function() end, false, false, true }

table.sort(A, function(a,b)
  if type(a) == type(b) and type(a) == 'number' then return a < b end
  return type(a)..tostring(a) < type(b)..tostring(b) end)
```

Will give you this:

```
{false, false, true, function() end, function() end,
 -100, 1, 1.1, 2, 3, 11, 12, "", "12", "2", "a", "b", "c", {}, {}, {}}
```

[Updated based on @tozka's comments]

Comment: This won't sort the numbers in the correct order `A = { 1, 2, 21, 12 }` will give this `1, 12, 2, 21`

Comment: @tozka, updated with a slightly more complex version that should handle that.

Comment: Now you have almost the oposite problem, while `A = { 2, 12 }` will sort all right (because we are sorting numbers). `A = { "2", "12" }`  (note that now we are sorting strings and not numbers) will give `{ "2", "12" }` where the correct sorted order of strings is `{ "12", "2" }`

Comment: Right; I'll argue it's more 'natural' this way ;)

Comment: @downvoters, would be nice to have a comment on what you disagree with. Style? Substance? Formatting?

Comment: I did say. The task says that 'numbers and strings should be sorted as usual' while you are sorting strings that can be converted to number as numbers (not as strings). Nor does it group them as required, example: `A = { 1, 2, "1", "2" }` is sorted as {1, "1", 2, "2"} when it should be {1, 2, "1", "2"}

Comment: @tozka, I saw your feedback; my question was for the other person. Valid point. I think the updated version should satisfy all the requirements.